# How to return FirstOrDefaultAsync EF Linq to entity List query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-6

I have this Linq to entity query that returns a list of visitors with joins.
I want a similar query to return a single record without the query being a List collection, but changing it to a basic select with `FirstOrDefaultAsync` gets the error `"A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause"`

```cs
public async Task<List<VisitorDetail>> GetOneVisitor(int visitorId)
{
    var query = await (from v in _context.Visitors
        where v.Id == visitorId
        join d in _context.Categories on v.VisitCategoryId equals d.Id
        join c in _context.Counters on v.AssignedCounter equals c.Host into counterGroup
        from cg in counterGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            FirstName = v.FirstName,
            LastName = v.LastName,
            CounterDescription = cg.Description,
            VisitCategory = d.Description
        }).ToListAsync();

    List<VisitorDetail> visitors = new();

    foreach (var p in query)
    {
        visitors.Add(new VisitorDetail
        {
            FirstName = p.FirstName,
            LastName = p.LastName,
            CounterDescription = p.CounterDescription,
            CategoryDescription = p.VisitCategory
        });
    }
    return visitors;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep DRY with LINQ to Entities, return `IQueryable` for your common queries and invoke materialization only when it is needed.

Your method can be rewritten in the following way:

```cs
public IQueryable<VisitorDetail> GetVisitorDetails(int visitorId)
{
    var query = 
        from v in _context.Visitors
        where v.Id == visitorId
        join d in _context.Categories on v.VisitCategoryId equals d.Id
        join c in _context.Counters on v.AssignedCounter equals c.Host into counterGroup
        from cg in counterGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new VisitorDetail
        {
            FirstName = v.FirstName,
            LastName = v.LastName,
            CounterDescription = cg.Description,
            CategoryDescription = d.Description
        };

    return query;
}
```

```cs
var many = await GetVisitorDetails(visitorId).ToListAsync();
var one  = await GetVisitorDetails(visitorId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```